# Problemas con librería Pulp

Tags: python-3.x

Hola buenas estoy trabajando en un problema de cobertura máxima junto a la libreria solver, pero esta me a estado arrojando un problema al ejecutar el comando:

`mclp_from_cm = mclp_from_cm.solve(solver)`

El error arrojado es:

`PulpSolverError: Pulp: cannot execute cbc.exe cwd: C:\Users\...`.

No se si alguien sabe como solucionar este problema porque ya he intentado todo lo posible junto a la libreria pulp.

De ante mano muchas gracias!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.